# WCF: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am pretty new to WCF and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.
Basically, I am trying to pull information from an existing WCF which was not developed by me.

So, for testing purposes, I created a console application and added the svc as a service reference.
I create a new instance of the client, and whenever I try to execute any of the methods, I get the following error:

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
```

Does this mean the WCF requires a signed certificate to authenticate the client?
If this is the case, do I need to request/provide anything from/to the WCF's provider?

I´ve looked through several post related to this issue, but all these scenarios are based on the assumption that you have access to the server.

**EDIT**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="..." />
                <binding name="SecureByTransport">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/Web/ConnectWcf.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ConnectBasic"
                contract="ConnectBasic.IConnectBasic" name="BasicHttpBinding_IConnectBasic" />
            <endpoint address="https://localhost/Web/ConnectBasicWcf.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureByTransport"
                contract="ConnectBasic.IConnectBasic" name="SecureByTransport" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Interesting. You have an endpoint with an HTTP scheme, but Security Mode is set to Transport. I have a feeling that the generated app.config file is incorrect. I hate to say it, but having the configuration on the server would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Derek for taking the time to review this. What do you mean by having the config on the server?

Comment: The server should have a config file as well (web.config or app.config) depending on the hosting scenario.